# Ruby : any way to install Rails.logger for CLI apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging

I have some Ruby code that I am testing stand alone before integrating into a Rails app.  Because the final app. is in Rails I have numerous calls to Rails.logging.xxx that I want in there, but with these I can't run the stand alone app because it doesn't know about Rails.logging.  How can I set it up so I can have these logging calls both in my CLI test app. and work in the final Rails deployment?

TY,
Fred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just create a simple stub logger that is only available in the CLI version? For example:

```
class Rails
  def self.logger
     @logger ||= Logger.new('cli_logger.log')
  end
end

Rails.logger.info("Spam")
```

Or perhaps more [Rails-like](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger):

```
class Rails
  cattr_accessor :logger
end

Rails.logger = Logger.new('cli_logger.log')
Rails.logger.info("It works")
```

Answer (score 0):

why you cant use the logger in your app?
just use it like an normal debugger?

see http://ruby.about.com/od/tasks/a/logger.htm